# How to trim an exterior door to fit new flooring

Tags: doors, flooring, metal, cutting

I am putting in new hardwood flooring and the level of my floor was raised a good 1.5". As a result I had to cut all my door and jambs, which was fine for the interior doors. I naively took the saw to my porch and front door and saw sparks fly. I assume there is some metal in there or something. How can I take off like an inch off the bottom of these reinforced doors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take your door off and get a good look at the bottom. There's a fair chance it's an aluminum or steel skin on a wood core. If so, you'll want to get a blade (I'm assuming circular saw is your weapon of choice, here) that's rated for whatever you've got. In addition, you'll want a U-shaped door sweep (well, 3 sides of a box, really) to cover up any nasty metal edges.

Best practice would be to splash a bit of primer on the raw wood you've exposed.

Depending on the configuration of your door, a new threshold might be a good thing.

At a minimum, wear eye and ear protection... a nuisance dust mask is also a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in the past:

Cut door with saw and blade made for metal cutting. On a door I was working on, the amount removed (1 1/2") compromised the wood framework/block at the bottom of the door on the inside, beneath the "skin", which was tin. I then carefully cut a new wood block, chiseled out the foam insulating core to the proper depth, and installed it into the bottom of the door with glue and finish nails.